# How do I save a Blob[0] (.pdf file) to a specified folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to create a script that willsave a .pdf file to a specific folder without much luck.
The file always saves to My Drive root folder.  I have found a number of examples with similar subject and have tried all of them but none have worked.

My last attempt produces an error message: 
Cannot find function createFile in object FolderIterator. (line 43, file "Code")
Below is the code I am using.

```
 var range = PayoutSheet.getRange("O1:T1");
 var ID = "1YlcoW81mYPmbddpXGm1xcNhT5JHj2-ey";  // 
 var MogaData = "MOGA_data";  // tried using this var instead of what is in quotes below.  
 var driveFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("MOGA_data");  // this is the folder I want to save to.
 var file = driveFolder.createFile(Blobs[0]);   //   this is line 43
 file.setName("MyFile");
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure about ``Blobs[0]``, if the folder of ``MOGA_data`` is only one in your Drive, how about trying ``var driveFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("MOGA_data").next();``? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfoldersbynamename

Comment: As stated in the comment above, you need to use `next()` to actually get the folder.  What you are getting now is called a "Folder Iterator"  It's not the actual folder.  And don't put periods in your comments.  There is a code editor bug that causes the context menu to stop working if you put periods in your comments.

Comment: Thanks    The MOGA_data folder is one of many folders    I didn't know about the next() requirement as I am new to google script coding